# GetPosition() not working with wxPython

Tags: python, widget, wxpython

I'm new to Python (and programming in general) so forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I'm following a tutorial in a book for creating a GUI in Python. Right now I'm learning about how to make a Spin Control increment some static text. When I run it, the spin control shows up but the console says "value = event.GetPosition()
AttributeError: 'CommandEvent' object has no attribute 'GetPosition'"

The code is:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,\
          title=title, size=(300,250))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sc = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, value='0', pos=(130, 50), size=(70, 25))
        self.valueText = wx.StaticText(panel, label='', pos=(130,80))

        sc.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self.spinControl)

    def spinControl(self, event):
        # Get spin control value
        value = event.GetPosition()
        # Update static text
        self.valueText.SetLabel(str(value))

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame("wxPython Widgets!")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

That code is literally copy/pasted from the book's website. I have wxPython installed and everything works perfectly up to that point.

Halp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working through that same book *Python in a Day 2*.  I believe the content is already outdated.

> If you change the line with GetPosition() to
>
> value = event.GetEventObject().GetValue()

is correct.  I can confirm that it works for Python 2.7.11.

Jeremiah

Answer (score 0):

If you change the line with GetPosition() to

```
value = event.GetEventObject().GetValue()
```

it will work. The event just doesnt have the GetPosition attribute, so it cannot eb executed.

If you want to check which functions and attributes are available, you can use

```
print(dir(event))
```

This will show you everything which is available inside the event.

Michael